# How to Publish Binary Data Using Thingsboard and MQTT API?

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

Per [Thingsboard documentation](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#key-value-format),
By default, ThingsBoard supports key-value content in JSON. Key is always a string, while value can be either string, boolean, double or long. Using custom binary format or some serialization framework is also possible. See [protocol customization](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#protocol-customization) for more details...

However, the [protocol customization](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#protocol-customization) does not say much details. Can someone give more details about how to do publish binary data in Thingsboard using its MQTT API? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in the Thingsboard Documentation (v1.3 at this time). Please refer to the [Extensions (Plugins and Actions) Development Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/extensions-development/#action-development-guide).

Comment: Please out line the basics of the answer here, as link only answers become useless when the link breaks

Comment: Hi, How to redirect to custome login page to thingsboard.io/home using auth/login API, Please if you have knowledge can you share with us.

Comment: Yep, the link is broken now and the answer is useless.

Comment: IoT platforms are very immature, thus change very rapidly. The documentation does not keep up.